# Can CosmosDB (DocumentDB) Xamarin and dot .net standard library.

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb, .net-standard

I know that CosmosDB (documentdb) is not compatible with a PCL with Xamarin forms.  All the examples I can find use a shared library.

Is CosmosDB (documentdb) compatible with Xamarin Forms using a dot net standard library?  Are there any code examples?

Any suggestions or should we just stick with the Shared Library method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.Azure.documentdb.Core is compatible with .net standard 1.6 or greater so standard libraries are a option.  Personally I prefer to put the database access in a web service I create to keep my database connection info secure

Comment: Just to add to Ken's answer, here is the [NetStandard package link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core).